# Derivatives distribution

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $f$ be a distribution on $\mathbf{R}^n$ (in the Schwartz sense) such that
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} = 0 \text{ for $i = 1, \ldots, n$.}$$

Then how to prove that $f$ is a constant? I had this exercise in a class last year but I couldn't find how to do the induction step (for $n = 1$ it is clear of course).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For $\partial f/\partial x_i$ to vanish, then $f$
has to vanish on the space of test functions of the form
$\partial \phi_i/\partial x_i$. You effectively need to
show the subspace spanned by all of these (as $i$ varies)
is of codimension one in $C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$. This subspace
has to be the space of all test functions integrating to zero.
To go from
$n-1$ to $n$, take a test function $\phi$ with integral $0$ and let
$\psi(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})=\int\phi(x_1,\ldots,x_n)dx_n$.
Then $\psi$ is a test function on $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$
with integral $0$ so is a sum of functions
$\partial \psi_i/\partial x_i$ where the $\psi_i$ are test
functions on $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. Extend to test functions
$\phi_i$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ by letting $\phi_i(x_1,\ldots,x_n)
=\psi_i(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})h(x_n)$ where $h$ is a fixed bump function
with integral $1$. Then $\phi-\sum\partial\phi_i/\partial x_i$
has zero integral along all lines in the $x_n$-direction,
so is the $x_n$-partial derivative of a test function.

**Added**
I should add that the above is effectively the proof that
$H_c^n(\mathbb{R}^n)=\mathbb{R}$ where $H_c^*$ denotes de Rham
cohomology with compact supports.

Comment: This is actually the type of argument I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Some explanations about Robin Chapman's wonderful proof. To complete the last step, define  $\phi_n(x_1,\dots,x_n)= \int_{-\infty}^{x_n} (\phi(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1},t) -\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \partial\phi_i/\partial x_i(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1},t)) dx_n$. $\phi_n$ turns out to be a test function and $\phi=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \partial\phi_i/\partial x_i$. This completes the inductive step and so the proof. Now choose a test function $\psi$ such that $\int \psi(x) dx = 1$. If $\phi$ is a test function, with $\int \phi(x) dx = c$, then $\phi= (\phi - c \psi) + c \psi$, so ...

Answer (score 6):

If $f(x)$ is a smooth function, one gets that $f(x)$ is constant relatively easily as in Shai Covo's comment. For a general distribution, one can convolve with approximations to the identity: Let $\phi(x)$ be a fixed smooth function with compact support such that $\int \phi(x) = 1$, and let $\phi_k(x) =  k^n\phi(kx)$.

Recall $f \ast \phi_k$ is a smooth function (the integral of $<f, \phi_y>$ with respect to $y$, where $\phi_y$ is the translate of $\phi$ by $y$) and is defined by $<f \ast \phi_k, s> = <f(x) , s \ast \phi_k(x)>$ for $C_c(R^n)$ functions $s(x)$. Since $s \ast \phi_k(x)$ converges to $s(x)$ uniformly, with the same property holding for derivatives of $s(x)$, $f \ast \phi_k$ converges to $f$ as distributions.

But each $f \ast \phi_k(x)$ is a smooth function, and $<f \ast \phi_k, \partial_i s(x)>$ $=$  $<f(x), \partial_i s \ast \phi_k(x)>$ $=$  $<f(x), \partial_i (s \ast \phi_k(x))>$ $= 0$ by assumption. Hence by the smooth function case $f \ast \phi_k(x)$ is a constant. Thus $f(x)$ is the distributional limit of constants and must be constant itself.

Comment: Ah, I didn't think of this, I was trying some approach similar to Robin Chapman's. However his approach uses less machinery (like that the approximated sequence converges in $L^p$). I'll see which one gets the most upvotes to see which one I will accept since both are good.

Comment: It is usually what I try when I need a fact about distributions that is easy to show for the case of smooth functions.

Comment: great idea!! But I think you also need $\int \phi=1$ for $f\ast \phi_k$ converge to $f$ as distribution

Comment: Thanks, corrected.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \neq (y_1,\ldots,y_n)$. If we fix $x_2,\ldots,x_n$, then $f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ is constant with respect to $x_1$. Hence, $f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) = f(y_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$. Next, fix $y_1,x_3,\ldots,x_n$. Then, $f(y_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ is constant with respect to $x_2$. Hence, $f(y_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) = f(y_1,y_2,\ldots,x_n)$. Continue this way to conclude that $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = f(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$, that is, $f$ is constant.

Comment: It is quite non obvious, but I am pretty sure that the question is talking about distributions in the sense of Schwartz, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_%28mathematics%29

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought it would be clear, I'll modify the question.

Comment: I should have realized from the tags that it isn't a trivial question...