# Weak derivative: Showing a function is equal to zero a.e.

Tags: weak-derivatives

I am very beginner in the theory of weak derivative. I am trying to fix the following problem:

Suppose that $f\in{L_{loc}^{1}}$ and $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\phi({x})dx=0$ for all $\phi\in{C_{0}^{\infty}}$ then $f(x)=0$ $a.e.$ on $(a,b)\subset{\mathbb{R}}$.

I will appreciate your ideas.

Comment: No apologies for trivial things! People here on this site are fond of it, since it gives them the opportunity to provide an answer. Continuously they are eagerly searching for that.

Comment: Do you believe that a $\phi$ can have small, measurable support and be positive?  (Typically called "bump functions".)  If so, what must the value of $f(x)$ be on that support? (and on every measurable subset of that support for which we can construct a suitable alternative bump function)

Comment: @drhab This one is actually far from being trivial.

Comment: @Algebra See for example here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78142/the-constant-distribution

Comment: @Etienne In the original question (there was an edit) the OP apologized for asking maybe something trivial. Only on that I wrote my comment. The question itself is beyond my scope.

Comment: @ Etienne: Thanks for providing a link for the similar problem.

Comment: @drhab I understand. Sorry if my comment sounded "agressive"; this was not at all my intention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One useful technique you can use here is regularization by convolution. For instance, a typical regularization result (that is relevant here) is the following:

> **Regularization:** Let $\phi\in C^\infty_0$ be nonnegative, with $\int \phi\,dx = 1$. For each $t>0$, define $\phi_t = t^{-1}\phi(x/t)$. Then for any $f\in L^1_{loc}$, the convolutions $f*\phi_t$ are smooth functions and $f*\phi_t\to f$ in $L^1_{loc}$ as $t\to 0$.

Now let's apply this result to your problem. Choose a $\phi$ as in the theorem. By definition, $$(f*\phi_t)(x) = \int f(y)\phi_t(x - y)\,dy.$$ But the function $y\mapsto \varphi_t(x - y)$ is a compactly supported smooth function, so by your assumption on $f$, the integral is $0$, i.e., $(f*\phi_t)(x) = 0$ for all $x$. That is to say $f*\phi_t \equiv 0$. As $t$ was arbitrary, if you let $t\to 0$ the regularization theorem says that $0 \equiv (f*\phi_t)\to f$ in $L^1_{loc}$. Thus $f = 0$ in $L^1_{loc}$.

Comment: But our case is $\phi:(a,b)\rightarrow{\mathbb{R}}$ then $x/t$ may not be in $(a,b)$ and then $\phi(x/t)$ is not defined. How do we control this issue?

Comment: @Algebra: you can always extend $\phi$ to a function defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$ simply by setting $\phi\equiv 0$ outside of $(a,b)$. This function remains compactly supported and smooth.